# Read each line of a text file to a new array element

Tags: php, arrays, text-files, explode, fread

I want to enter each line of this text file in to a new array element, and i need the array to end up like so: Array ( [testuser] => 'testpassword' ) by using this text in the text file: 'testuser' => 'testpass'

The code i have now:

```
$filename = "logininfo.txt";
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 
if ($fp) { $LOGIN_INFORMATION = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename))); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Use PHP's [`file`](http://php.net/file) function:</s>

```
$array = file('logininfo.txt');
```

To ignore newlines and empty lines, provide the appropriate flags:

```
$array = file('logininfo.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
```

A good way to solve this, is PHP's [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) function.
Your file will have to look slightly different though, but I assume that is not a problem:

```
; file contents:
testuser = testpass
```

And in your PHP file:

```
$array = parse_ini_file('logininfo.txt', FALSE);
```

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. I thought you wanted to have each line as an array entry. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is like this :

user : blah
password : somthing

you could do it like this

```
$arr = array();
$filename = "test.txt";
$fp = fopen( $filename, "r" );
while ( ! feof( $fp ) ) {
   $line = fgets( $fp, 1024 );
   $temp = explode(":", $line);
   $arr[trim($temp[0])] = trim($temp[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that was close, but i got this: Array (['testuser' => 'testpass']

Comment: Forget it, i got it now, forgot to change the text file to user: password ;) Thanks bro!